# Is it possible to write a sip client with google dart?

Tags: sip, dart

I am trying to write a **SIP-client** as a web page. Is it possible to perform it with **Google Dart**?

- If yes, is there any good start point for tutorial or boilerplate example codes?
- If no, what alternative should i use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at sipML5? It will be an alternative.

http://sipml5.org/

Comment: Yes i pushed it to my research stack :), still i am new to web development and , while using dart, it would be great if dart solves my problem.

Comment: Although this solution look like based on javascript and not dart, this is the best option available. It is also suggested on one of Google I/O 2012 talks about WebRTC to use sipML5. Marking it as a solution till DART team come up with some sweet magic :)